# Eclipse - I want to access a class from the same package but under a different project, how?

Tags: java, eclipse, package, visibility, class-visibility

I use Eclipse IDE for my Java projects and all my projects(`Project_1`,`Project_2` and so on) related classes are inside a package `package_name`.

I am currently working on 2 classes.

`class_name.java`(`Project_2`/`package_name`)

`utility.java`(`Project_1`/`package_name`)

All methods are `public`.
How can I use the methods within `utility.java` in `class_name.java` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a jar file from the source package and import it in the classpath of Project_2.

1- Right Click on desired package -> Export -> JAR File

2- Right Click on goal project -> build path -> Add external jar(or copy the jat file in lib folder of the second project and select the Add Jars in the Libraries tab of Java Build Path)

Comment: Why is it not immediately visible in `Project_2`?

Comment: Beacuase every projects have a independent build path that include necessary library(jar file) of the self project.

Answer (score 0):

If only one requires the other, you can use the Java Build Path property page of one project (Project 2) to have it require the other.